# How to make a number a function?

Tags: javascript, function, numbers

How would I execute a number as a function?

```
3();
```

And then there is the issue of defining it. How would I do that?

Comment: You don't. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: What makes you think that it's possible?

Comment: Please don't say possible duplicate.

Comment: @Prolight Why not? Doesn't the answer answer your question? If not, then please [edit] your post and explain why it doesn't.

Comment: It does answer it, but I wanted a simpler response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers are not allowed to be the first char of your function's name.
You could do something like

```
function _3(){...}
```